# Is there a shortcut key to select <inherit from parent or project defaults> in VS2010 property sheets?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsprops

I am moving a multi-project solution to use .props files instead of repeatedly defining properties in the projects. At the moment I am going through all the old projects and selecting "inherit from parent or project defaults" for most of the settings.

To help prevent RSI, is there any shortcut key for setting this on a particular property? For bonus points, is there a way of listing the changed (bold) properties for a particular configuration so I can review them all in one place?

Xcode does both of these things nicely (backspace to reset a property and an option to just show settings defined at the current level). Would be great if I could find an equivalent in VS2010!